# Blank MapCanvas Window

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt4

I am constructing a GUI using PyQT4 and QGis. Rigth now I can open the MapCanvas whith same buttons of Zoom In/Out using this code:

```
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QAction
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import SIGNAL, Qt
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

class MyWnd(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, layer):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)

        self.canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        self.canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])
        #self.canvas.setLayers([layer])


        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.actionZoomIn = QAction("Zoom in", self)
        self.actionZoomOut = QAction("Zoom out", self)
        self.actionPan = QAction("Pan", self)

        self.actionZoomIn.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionZoomOut.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionPan.setCheckable(True)

        self.actionZoomIn.triggered.connect(self.zoomIn)
        self.actionZoomOut.triggered.connect(self.zoomOut)
        self.actionPan.triggered.connect(self.pan)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Canvas actions")
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionZoomIn)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionZoomOut)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.actionPan)

        # create the map toolsq
        self.toolPan = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
        self.toolPan.setAction(self.actionPan)
        self.toolZoomIn = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, False) # false = in
        self.toolZoomIn.setAction(self.actionZoomIn)
        self.toolZoomOut = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, True) # true = out
        self.toolZoomOut.setAction(self.actionZoomOut)

        self.pan()

    def zoomIn(self):
        self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomIn)

    def zoomOut(self):
        self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomOut)

    def pan(self):
        self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolPan)



`Teste Application:
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 2.18", True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()

layer=QgsVectorLayer('C:/ProgramFiles(x86)/QGIS2.18/gis_data/PRT_water_areas_dcw.shp', 'water','org')

w = MyWnd(layer)
w.show()

qgs.exec_()
qgs.exitQgis()`
```

However, I am getting a blank MapCanvas with nothing on it that crushes my program. I think that it is related to this line:

```
self.canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])
```

But I cant understand why this is happening.